# changing pages in google sign with android studio

Tags: android, google-signin, data-transfer

I have tried for several weeks now to get my Google sign-in Button on my app to change pages and transfer information but I cannot seem to find the right code. If somebody could give me a hand I will display my Google sign-in button code down below :

This is my activity_sign_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="sign_in"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

please help!!

Comment: Can you show your Java code that would listen for the click event?

Comment: I do not have that yet this is all I have I need help. could you please help?

Comment: You shouldn't have XML without Java, so please show your Activity code